# vb.net sending datagridview content to client side

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a chat system for my company and what i have now is a functional chat with (on the server) a list that contains all logged in users and their nickname.

What i want to do is to send this datagridview to every client when a new employee enters the chat.

How can i do this?
i tried to convert my gridview into a dataset.writexml but that doesn't work.

the only thing i use now are some commands to send the messages:

Send("#MSG#Hello everyone")

Send("#LOGIN# #1#Username#2#Employeename")

Send("#LOGOUT# #1#Username#2#Employeename") 
...

I'm using a multi threaded socket server/client system.

Thanks for helping out

Comment: You server already receive all the events. It should just store them somewhere and when someone new connect it should send all these events to him, the same way you already do when someone send a new event. You shouldn't bother about dataview.

Comment: okay, i did this and it works,  i'm new with vb so i'm wondering if "Send" is the only command i can use to communicate,   is there a way to make e socket communication like  Send1("ChatMessage") Read1(Str)   send2("Username", "UserCode"), read2(UserName, UC) ,,,